# std::regex escape "+" sign

Tags: c++, regex, c++14

I dont understand exactly how the escaping with regex word. 
I try to detect a "+". I know it is also a special sign of regex to indicate that there follows one ore more signs.

From my understanding these special signs need to be escaped with "\". For + this seems to work with "."  If i however escape a plus with "+ i get a runtime exception.

> "matched. regex_error(error_badrepeat): One of *?+{ was not preceded
>   by a valid reguar expression."

So I assume it is not correctly escaped.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <exception>



int main() 
try {
    std::regex point("\.");

    std::string s1 = ".";
    if (std::regex_match(s1, point))
        std::cout << "matched" << s1;

    std::regex plus("\+");

    std::string s2 = "+";
    if (std::regex_match(s2, plus))
        std::cout << "matched" << s2;

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

}
catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what()<<'\n';

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
}
catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "unknown error\n";

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
}
```

Comment: Escape the \, so you actually have it in your string. It gives \\+.

Comment: Or use a raw string, `r"(\+)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a C++ string literal, where `\` is a special character, and should be escaped. So you should use `"\\+"`.

To avoid double escaping, you can also use [raw string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), e.g. `R"(\+)"`.

Answer (score 0):

DOT `.`, plus sign `+` are special characters for regex operation in C++. So you have to do it like below:-

```
    regex point("\\.");
```